# Wait on Class Method to be finished C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download, wait

I need to Download a File from a Https Source. 
I'll do this asynchron like this (works so far):

```
void doChecksbeforDownload(){
//Do some Checks
   DownloadFileAsync();

}

void DownloadFileAsync(){
     ...
     ... 
     this.client.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
     this.client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     this.client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", PostParameter);
     ...
     ...
}
```

and call the client_UploadStringCompleted() Method when finished:

```
void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do Check here
    }
```

So far so good. Now I put all this in a class "Functions" and call the Method like this:

```
 Functions f = new Functions();
 f.doChecksbeforeDownload();
```

I want doChecksbeforeDownload() to wait until the clientUloadStringCompleted is FINISHED.

How do I do I tell doChecksbeforeDownload to wait until the the Async call in DownloadFilesAsync is done and ready.

1. Call doChecksbeforeDownload()
2. ChecksbeforeDownload()->DownloadFileAsync()
3. ChecksbeforeDownload()->Waits.......
4. DownloadFileAsync() -> Completet & Ready
5. ChecksbeforeDownload()->returns FOO to Main Class

Are there any best practices / examples to achieve this? I stuck in this point.

Thanks in advance

Hannes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use the synchronization objects exposed in .NET.

Check out [this link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent).  Here's an excerpt:

```
class BasicWaitHandle
{
  static EventWaitHandle _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent (false);

  static void Main()
  {
    new Thread (Waiter).Start();
    Thread.Sleep (1000);                  // Pause for a second...
    _waitHandle.Set();                    // Wake up the Waiter.
  }

  static void Waiter()
  {
    Console.WriteLine ("Waiting...");
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();                // Wait for notification
    Console.WriteLine ("Notified");
  }
}
```

NOTE: Be careful making your reset events static, etc.  Then you'll be introducing thread safety issues.  The above example is only static for simplicity.

In your case, you'd want to make to make the autoreset event a member of your class that is performing the asynchronous.  In your function, after you start the asynchronous call, wait on your handle.  In the completion event, set your event which should unblock your wait handle.

Consider that you may want to introduce timeouts for the call to WaitOne(), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for some `WaitHandle` derived class to accomplish the task.

I would use [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)  as I think is one of the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just spit balling here, but how about this:

```
In DownloadFileAsync() set a flag like DownloadInProgress

In doChecksbeforeDownload
  If DownloadInProgress Then set flag WaitingForDownloadCompletion
  Else Continue

In client_UploadStringCompleted()
  Set DownloadInProgress = false
  If WaitingForDownloadCompletion Then call doChecksbeforeDownload()
```

Comment: Can I do this in a simple WHILE Loop? Or Do I have to take this in a own thread and watch this if its running?

    In doChecksbeforeDownload
      If DownloadInProgress Then set flag WaitingForDownloadCompletion
     Else Continue

Comment: No loop required. When the download completes it fires UploadStringCompletedEventHandler. The delegate you've written then calls the doChecksbeforeDownload, but now the flag saying a download is already in progress has been cleared so it can go ahead with the rest of it's work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bool variable at the classlevel like

bool isFinished = false;

Then have your async set this value to true once it is done.

Then expose the isFinished varible as a public value.

Comment: hi and thanks for your answer: Same questions as one comment before:

Can I do this in a simple WHILE Loop? Or Do I have to take this in a own thread and watch this if its running?

Comment: You can use the while loop, but what your CPU load. Running a query or other methods inside a while loop can easily consume your resources. Consider using thread.sleep to avoid checking all the time.